# Should a Model deal with multiple values of itself?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Given a table called transactions, I have a model like:

```
class Transaction extends Eloquent {
    // other methods including some scopes

    public static function getInteresting()
    {
        $data = Transaction::with('location', 'user', 'type')
        ->category(1)
        ->salesGroup(3)
        ->confirmed();

        return $data->get();
    }
}
```

So, let's say that these 'Interesting' transactions are used very frequently – should I be returning multiple Transactions from the Transaction model? If not, where should that code live?

Comment: [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) instance is not "model"

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add a static method like that. I've been using Respositories for situations like this, where there is some common DB interaction that is used in several places. As a bonus your complex data logic is abstracted if you ever need to change data sources later on.

I see you are also aware of scopes so you could also just create a scope and include all of the above within it.

```
public function scopeInteresting($query)
{
    $query->with('location', 'user', 'type')
        ->category(1)
        ->salesGroup(3)
        ->confirmed();
}

$transactions = Transaction::interesting()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think also that repositories are good solution to place code. They bring a lot of flexibility and decouple model from controller. I use them to provide two db implementations to my controllers - mongo and mysql. You could create your own service layer, but your code is concerned with db so repositories are option to go.

Comment: Why would your controllers care about what sort of storage is used deep underneath? Or even if there is any persistent storage **at all**...

Answer (score 1):

Here where I work, we use three layers to solve this problem.

The `Entity` represents (obviously) an entity, such as a transaction. It contains fields and setters e getters to those fields.

The `DAO` provides methods to acess the database, related to a specific entity.

The `BO` provides methods that do the business logic of our applications.

So, in your case:
The `DAO\Transaction` will perform a query, and return multiple `Entity\Transaction` instances.

Hope this helps.